# GeOrchestra: what do I have to do when it displays "site on maintenance"?

Tags: georchestra

I'm testing GeOrchestra to share maps between collegues. I've used the ansible script to install it and it was working fine. Today, connecting to the server displays a message that the site is on maintenance.

Original message in french: "En raison d’une opération de maintenance, les services geOrchestra sont momentanément indisponibles. "

I have no idea of what I have to do regarding this message. I've restarted the server but this does not solve anything.

Any idea of what has happened and what can I do to disable the maintenance mode?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that, for some reason, Apache is not able to contact the security-proxy (HTTP 503 unavailable), and as a result, displays the ErrorDocument /errors/50x.html as per https://github.com/georchestra/georchestra/blob/17.12/docs/setup/apache.md#configuration

Is your servlet container (tomcat-proxycas) hosting the security-proxy up and running ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the configuration files mentioned in the link are present and seems correctly configured, but I have no idea on how to check if the servlet container is up and running. Can you help me on that?

Comment: I've found that there was no java services running on the ports used by proxycas. I think that the server has been restarted and georchestra was simply down. I've used the following instruction to restart it, but I'm not sure that it is what has to be done: /srv/tomcat/proxycas/bin/startup.sh && /srv/tomcat/georchestra/bin/startup.sh && /srv/tomcat/geoserver/bin/startup.sh. The message is gone but the display remains uncomplete. What am I missing?

Comment: What does "ps aux | grep tomcat" displays ? IIRC, it should list 3 tomcat instances: tomcat-proxycas, tomcat-georchestra, tomcat-geoserver.

Comment: To restart a tomcat instance, just "sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat-proxycas restart"

Comment: ps aux | grep tomcat is displaying the 3 tomcat instances. The maintenance message is gone, but the only thing displayed is the geoserver page, but without georchestra navigation headers. Geonetwork is not reachable.

Comment: I've tried to relaunch my ansible script to be sure that everything was ok, but the following file declared in the vars of georchestra postgresql is missing on github and the script fails:
https://raw.github.com/georchestra/georchestra/master/postgresql/04-ldapadmin.sql

Do you know if it is available somewhere else? I've submitted an issue on github too.